# Append summed columns as rows to dataframe, over for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe:

```
TripID, x, y
adasd,  2, 3
adasd,  3, 2
adasd,  -1, 3
fgrgr,  4, 1
ect...
```

and a list of all my TripIDs. Currently what I'm trying to do is create a For loop where I make a temporary dataframe of each TripID, perform a calculation on it, then append the output to a new dataframe. An example temp dataframe is:

```
TripID,  x,  y,  z,   a
adasd,   2,  3,  3,   1.019460
adasd,   3,  2, -1,   1.319678
adasd,  -1,  3,  N/A, N/A
```

and I'd like to add the following row to the output dataframe:

```
adasd, 2.339138
```

My code is:

```
for ID in tripList:
    temp = df.loc[df['TripID'] == ID]
    temp['z'] = temp['x'].shift(periods=-1)
    temp['a'] = np.vectorize(myfunction)(temp['x'],temp['y'],temp['z'])
    temp2 = temp.groupby('TripID')['a'].sum()
    temp2 = temp2.reset_index()
    output = pd.concat([output,temp2])
```

My desired output is a dataframe with two columns, one for tripID and another for my 'a' value. I don't want it to have any repeated IDs. However I can't concat my temp2 variable as it converts it into a series instead of a dataframe.

Let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: Can you add `Distance` column and some sample `myfunction` with desired output?

Comment: Also column `z` is missing.

Comment: Sorry, that was left in from when I copied and pasted my code. the distance column should be 'a' which I've fixed in my question.

Comment: Assume your series has same columns as your dataframe, you can do `output = output.append(temp2, ignore_index=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of my previous version using groupby:

```
temp2 = temp.groupby('TripID')['a'].sum()
temp2 = temp2.reset_index()
output = pd.concat([output,temp2])
```

I instead created a new dataframe with the code:

```
Suma = temp['a'].sum()
trpId = temp['TripID'].iloc[0]
temp2 = pd.DataFrame([[trpId,Suma]],columns=['TripID','a'])
output = pd.concat([output,temp2])
```